# Como fazer um implode para remover outros caracteres além do sinal +(mais) com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Possuo essa variável: `10 + 20 + 30 + 40 + 50 = 150`.

Quero saber como eu posso usar o `implode()` do JavaScript para retirar qualquer coisa que estiver na frente de cada numero, pode ser qualquer sinal ou caracteres especiais, essa string pode ter também vários tamanhos.

Resultado desejado:

```
var numero = 10 + 20 + 30 + 40 + 50 = 150;

var 10 = 10
var 20 = 20
var 30 = 30
var 40 = 40
var 50 = 50

var igual = 150
```

Meu código:

```
var valor = "10+20+30+40+50=150";
var separar = valor.split('+');//Nesse caso fica limitado ao sinal de adição
alert(adicao);
```

Comment: o `implode` só transforma em array uma string separada por caracteres distintos, e esses caracteres não vão junto com o valor guardado. Retirar sinais, deve-se usar uma expressão regular, no caso do array transformado, usando um laço.

Comment: Lembrando q você não pode criar variáveis iniciando com números.

Comment: Pode ser ( n_10 ) ( n_20 ) e assim por diante

Comment: `valor.replace('=','+').split('+')` dessa maneira você terá um array com todos os valores, na mesma ordem que estão na sua variável. Isso ajuda?

Comment: Então, pode ser qualquer sinal ou qualquer caracteres especiais, pode ser ( 10@10) / (10/10) / (10*10 ) ou qualquer outro sinal aritmético ou caracter especial.

Comment: O que você vai fazer com esses valores? Isso é o mais importante, isso é que define qual precisa ser o formato da saída.

Comment: ou ainda, pode usar um regex no split, assim: `valor.split(/\D/)`

Answer (score 4):

Utilize um REGEX dentro do split

- Nesse caso `\D` quer dizer que irá realizar o "split" sempre que encontrar um carácter que não seja numérico.

```js
var valor = "10+20+30+40+50=150";
var valoresSeparados = valor.split(/\D/).map(function(item) {
    return parseInt(item, 10);
});
console.log(valoresSeparados);
```

Comment: Se houver dois caracteres sequenciais não-numéricos a sua solução coloca um item em branco no array, tem problemas nisto ai.

Comment: @GabrielKatakura "na frente de cada numero, pode ser qualquer sinal ou caracteres especiais", deu a entender que terá um caractere, e segundo o exemplo postado na questão sugere a mesma coisa.

Comment: Exatamente, mas isso não é um problema, segundo o AP, ele quer separar os números dos demais caracteres, se tiverem dois caracteres não terá sentido para o AP.

Comment: Então, é quase isso, teria que quardar cada numero separado em uma variavel de nome diferente e o valor da variavel é um numero inteiro sem aspas. Exemplo: var_10 = 10 / var_20 = 20

Comment: Você quer criar **uma variável para cada número**?? Qual é o problema em usar um array? Aliás, como você pretende que o código crie variáveis pra você? Digo, isso é até possível, mas que entender o que você pretende.

Comment: Depois vou manipular as variaveis, e cada valor tem que estar em uma variavels separa, menos o sinal de ( = ) que ficara em uma variavel chamada IGUAL var igual = 150

Comment: Utilizei um Array.map() para converter os itens do array em inteiro, agora, na minha opinião, acho que é melhor utilizar os valores dentro do array.

Comment: abduzeedo, no array o valores estão separados, acho que não tem necessidade de atribuir eles a outras variáveis, e você sempre terá na última posição do array o resultado.

Comment: Desculpe, alguem poderia me ajudar aconcluir esse topico ? eu preciso inserir os arrays em values do getElementById

Comment: Ai é outra pergunta, você pode procurar por `como inserir valores em elementos html com javascript` aqui mesmo no SOPT, tem muitas perguntas relacionadas.. se não encontrar, poste uma pergunta. :)

Answer (score 2):

É isso que você quer?

```js
var valor = "10++-20++30+40+50";
var variaveis = "";
var separar = valor.match(/(\d+)/g);

separar.forEach(function(x, indice) {
  variaveis += "var n_" + indice + " = " + x + ";\n";
});

eval(variaveis); // executando o eval para adicionar as variaveis criadas acima

var resultado = "";

separar.forEach(function(x, indice) {
  resultado += "n_" + indice + (indice == separar.length - 1 ? "" : " + ");
}); // rodando um foreach criar a linha q irá somar as variaveis

var igual = eval(resultado);

console.log("Resultado: " + igual);
```

Comment: Olá 10.2mil, nesse codigo fornecido gentilmente por você, ele separa os numeros independente do sinal aritmético ou caracteres especial que estiver entre os numeros ?

Comment: Separar somente os números. Independente do separador ser + ou - (menos).

Comment: Até editei pra você ver.

Comment: Tem como separar independe do sinal aritmético ou caractere especial ?

Comment: Ele já faz isso, usando o `match(/(\d+)/g)`, ele só separa os números.

Comment: legal amigo, só tenho mais uma duvida, eu gostaria de exibir os valores das variaveis em uma DIV, onde eu insiro isso ? Pois fiquei em duvida quanto ao ( eval ) que você criou que concatena tudo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47613/discussion-between-abduzeedo-and-l).